# Multiple collection view in a view controller - not set delegates for all of them

Tags: ios, collectionview

I am having 2 collection views in my view controller I want to have `collectionView sizeForItemAt` method just for one of them and not change the other one.

**I have to set other delegates for both of them.**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if (collectionView == collectionView1) {
            return CGSize(width: 158, height: 90)
        } else if (collectionView == collectionView2) {
           let collectionWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - 20) / 3

            return CGSize(width: collectionWidth, height: collectionWidth)
        } 
    }
```

I don't want to return anything for `collectionview2` because its size is dynamic and based on device size. which is done by a flowLayout.
Is there a way just to implement this method for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the cells of `collectionView1` has the same size. If so, use `estimatedItemSize`. It is an instance property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

> estimatedItemSize
>
> The estimated size of cells in the collection view. [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617709-estimateditemsize)

```
    let layoutOne = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layoutOne.estimatedItemSize =  CGSize(width: 158, height: 90)
    let collectionViewOne = CollectionViewOne(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layoutOne) 
     
    // CollectionView2 must have its own layout
    let layout =  UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionViewTwo = CollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

If you do so, remove `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`.